# hook_block_view not passing information

Tags: drupal-7, block

I am trying to build my first custom module in Drupal 7.  It is a block form for the user to search a DB table for customer information.  I've created both the module and info files.  My module appears under the modules and blocks section, but when I add the block to Content, the subject and content aren't being passed from my hook_block_view. So, instead of the form being displayed, it just shows the block title and body.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
<?php
/**
*@file
*
*/

/** Implements hook_block_info().
*
*/

function searchEngine_block_info(){
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['searchEngine_form'] = array (
        'info'  => t("Applicant Search"),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    );
    return $blocks;
}

/** Implements hook_block_view().
*
*/

function searchEngine_block_view($delta = ''){
    $block = array();
    switch($delta) {
        case 'searchEngine_form':
        $block['subject'] = t('Applicant Search');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('searchEngine_form');
    break;
    }
    return $block;
}

function searchEngine_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['searchOptions'] = array(
        '#type'     => 'select',
        '#title'    => t("Select how you would like to search for an applicant."),
        '#default_value'=> variable_get("gwf", true),
        '#options'  => array(
            'gwf'       => "GWF".t(" Number"),
            'email'     => t("Email"),
            'name'      => t("Name"),
            'phone_number'  => t("Phone Number"),
        ),

    );
    $form['data'] = array(
        '#type'     => 'textfeild',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('Submit'),
        );
        return $form;
}

function searchEngine_submit($form, $form_state) {
    if(isset($form['data'])){
        if($form['searchOptions'] == "name"){
            $name = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $form['data']);
            $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM tls_active_applicants WHERE first_name = '.$name['0'].' AND last_name = '.$name['1']);
        }else{
            $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM tls_active_applicants WHERE '.$form['searchOptions'].' = '.$form['data']);
        }
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a renderable array here is fine:

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('searchEngine_form');
```

I've just tested your code and the form appears fine for me:

[image]

Now we know the code works it makes me wonder if it is just some css or something hiding it?

I would also install the devel module as it will help with debugging.

The you could use this code:

```
function searchEngine_block_view($delta = ''){
    $block = array();
    switch($delta) {
        case 'searchEngine_form':
        $block['subject'] = t('Applicant Search');
        $form = drupal_get_form('test_form');
        dpm($form); // call to dpm here to log if you are successfully getting the form at this point
        $block['content'] = $form;
    break;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I didn't notice any changes after making the change and refreshing.

Comment: I just tested your code it works fine for me. One thing you do need to change is renaming your function searchEngine_submit to searchEngine_form_submit to get that to work correctly.

Comment: So do you think it may be a problem with the install of drupal? The only thing that appears for me is what is in "Block Title" and "Block Body" in config.  I tried leaving these empty to see if my form would show if there was nothing for body, but body is required.  Someone mentioned that I might want to add a hook_block_configure, but I had no luck with that.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Most common Drupal question in the world, but... have you cleared the cache? If ever in doubt with Drupal clear the cache! You don't need hook_block_configure for what your doing at the moment.

Comment: One other thing I think you should try is renaming your form. When all else fails when I'm debugging any PHP I start renaming variables and functions. Maybe try search_engine_search_form. Just an idea.

Comment: Yep, removed block, uninstalled module, cleared cache, added back.  No Luck :-/

Comment: Do make any changes to the Config settings when you enable the block?  I've tried leaving it as default and changing it to <none> which leaves it blank, but still no content.  I've also tried just changing $block['content'] to a string, but nothing....

Comment: Is it possible to make a hook_block_configure so that it doesn't ask for the body or anything and just sends my info?

Comment: Hook block configure is used if you want a setting form for a particular block. E.g. you could edit the block and set what color the header is. When you use dmp on the $form object in hook_block_view can you see the array for the whole form?